# Catastrophic backtracking issue while parsing partial/incomplete json

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a very complex rexeg meant to parse a fixed schema json.
I know we are not supposed to parse jsons via regex but I am dealing with terabyte size json and am trying to implement a parallel json reader which identifies the target records in a buffer mode. i.e I take a a random chunk and find the matching records, the part of the buffer before the first match and the part after the last matches are combine with the partial buffers of the previous and next chunk for further analysis and so on.

given this, the regex works fine in identifying the first match and so on but gets stuck in a Catastrophic backtracking issue after the last valid match.

the regex below

```
{\s*
(?:
  \s*"negotiation_arrangement"\s*:\s*"[^"]+?"\s*,?\s*|
  \s*"name"\s*:\s*"[^"]+?",?\s*|
  \s*"billing_code_type"\s*:\s*"[^"]+?",?\s*|
  \s*"billing_code_type_version"\s*:\s*"[^"]+?",?\s*|
  \s*"billing_code"\s*:\s*"[^"]+?",?\s*|
  \s*"description"\s*:\s*"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*",?\s*|
  \s*"bundled_codes"\s*:\s*\[[^\]]*\]\s*,?|
  \s*"covered_service"\s*:\s*\[[^\]]*\]\s*,?|
  \s*"negotiated_rates"\s*:\s*(?:\[\s*
  (?:\s*\{\s*
  (?:
    \s*"provider_references"\s*:\s*\[[^"\[\]]+\]\s*,?\s*|
    (?:\s*"provider_groups"\s*:\s*\[\s*
      (?:{\s*
        (?:"npi"\s*:\s*\[[\d\,\s]*\]\s*,?\s*)|
        (?:"tin"\s*:\s*{\s*
          (?:"type"\s*:\s*"[^"]+"\s*,?\s*|
             "value"\s*:\s*"[^"]+"\s*,?\s*
          )+\s*\}\s*
        )\s*\}\s*,?\s*
      )+\s*],?
    )|
    (?:\s*"negotiated_prices"\s*:\s*\[\s*
      (?:\s*{\s*
        (?:\s*"negotiated_type"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"\s*,? 
          |\s*"negotiated_rate"\s*:\s*[\d\.]*\s*,? 
          |\s*"expiration_date"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"\s*,? 
          |\s*"billing_class"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"\s*,? 
          |\s*"additional_information"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"\s*,?
          |\s*"service_code"\s*:\s*(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|null),?
          |\s*"billing_code_modifier"\s*:\s*(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|null),?
          ){0,7}
      \s*\},?)+
    )+\s*\]
  ){0,3}\s*\},?
)+
\s*\]\s*,?)
)+\s*}
```

minimum partial json sample causing the issue

```
{
  "negotiated_rates": [
    {
      "provider_references": [
        532
      ],
      "negotiated_prices": [
        {
          "negotiated_rate": 3600
        }
```

you can find the sample failure example at https://regex101.com/r/iIoRPD/2

And a successful example at https://regex101.com/r/xZ8a2O/1

How do I prevent this or how do I add an iteration limit which exits the re.finditer function if it gets stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Have you looked at [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) or similar in order to use a proper parser instead?

Comment: @TedLyngmo ijson does work on random buffers with incomplete jsons, additionally ijson is a serial parser, I am looking to create a parallel json parser to suit my needs. Lastly I am not dealing with json new line files, but with regular json files

Comment: If the existing parsers don't do what you need, then write a parser that does. Regex is most probably the most inefficient (and error prone) tool for something like this

Comment: Using regex for short or non-complex matches may perform decently. In any other situation, writing a specialized parser without using regex is likely going to outperform the regex version. It's also a lot less likely to provide surprises, like the catastrophic backtracking. It also becomes easier to read and maintain. I really recommend that you drop the regex track for this. I've compared regex solutions to proper parsers on many occations and there has never been a case where a specialized parser performs worse than regex. Never.

Comment: Thank for your input but i choose to disagree

Comment: To reduce backtracking, you can use [atomic groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html). Your failed pattern with some atomic groups and a bit [improved **at regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/iIoRPD/5). If you are using Python < 3.11 it *does not support atomic groups*, you need to use [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). Just replace then `import regex as re`...